# Visual Basic function works in online compiler, but not in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

This is the code. It converts timestamp to total seconds. It works just fine. Here it outputs `42.2143012`

```
Module VBModule
    Sub Main()
        Console.WriteLine(ConvertToSeconds("00:00:42.2143012"))
    End Sub
    
    Function ConvertToSeconds(timestamp As String) As Double
    Dim hours As Integer, minutes As Integer, seconds As Integer, milliseconds As Integer
    Dim parts() As String, parts2() As String
    
    parts = Split(timestamp, ":")
    parts2 = Split(parts(2), ".")
    
    hours = Val(parts(0))
    minutes = Val(parts(1))
    seconds = Val(parts2(0))
    milliseconds = Val(parts2(1))
    
    ConvertToSeconds = (hours * 3600) + (minutes * 60) + seconds + (milliseconds / 10000000)
End Function

End Module
```

But in Excel, it outputs `#VALUE!`, which is unfortunately not what it should be doing. Of course I'm only using the function, not entire code with main. It says nothing more, so it's impossible for me to debug.

Comment: As we were trying to get to in your last question.  There is something wrong with your data.  You will need to step through the function and check each line as it processes and see if it is returning what you expect.

Comment: Change `Integer` to `Long`. `milliseconds = Val(parts2(1))` overflows otherwise. Note that Visual Basic, aka VB.Net, is not the same as VBA. If you want to debug your function, then one option is to call it from another subroutine, not from the worksheet. `Sub adfasd()`
    `Debug.Print ConvertToSeconds("00:00:42.2143012")`
`End Sub` shows the problematic line immediately.

Comment: I cannot reproduce.  I copied the string from your code and pasted it in a cell then ran the  function pointing at that cell and it worked without issue.

Comment: @ScottCraner - hmm, `milliseconds As Integer` would definitely overflow with a value of `2143012`?

Comment: yes, sorry it works if I change to Long. @BigBen